# Count Values from Table for each type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table 
UserId  [nvarchar(128)], Rating [varchar(170)] :values will be mostly 1,2,3 but can have exceptions

Rating contains 3 values [1,2, or 3]

I want to get a result something like

```
UserId Count(1's),Count(2's) Count(3's)

 1. 1001     10      8         2 
 2. 1002     5      10        3
```

Is it possible in a single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY UserId` to count for each user-id. Use `CASE` to count 1's, 2's and 3's separately:

```
select UserId,
       count(case when Rating = 1 then 1 end) as [Count(1's)],
       count(case when Rating = 2 then 1 end) as [Count(2's)],
       count(case when Rating = 3 then 1 end) as [Count(3's)]
from tablename
group by UserId
```

Comment: Tim Schmelter, those horrible square brackets... Doesn't MS SQL Server support ANSI SQL's double quotes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement in each `COUNT` and then `GROUP BY` UserId.

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '1' THEN 1 END) AS [Count(1's)], COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '2' THEN 1 END) AS [Count(2's)], COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '3' THEN 1 END) AS [Count(3's)]
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT
  UserId, 
  COALESCE([1],0) [Count(1's)],
  COALESCE([2],0) [Count(2's)],
  COALESCE([3],0) [Count(3's)]
FROM
  ýour_table
PIVOT
  (COUNT([Rating])  
FOR Rating
  in([1],[2],[3])  
  )AS p
ORDER BY 
  UserId
```

Comment: I will check this , COUNT with CASE worked so marking that as answer , Seems to have some problem it is taking too much time for 100,000 rows with 3 users  - Thanks for the reply

Comment: @AdilAhamed I don't understand. Which answer had the performance issues ?